# Upgrading Xcode 3.2.4 to 3.2.5. Uninstall First?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Will XCode installer automatically update my old version or do I need to uninstall old one first?

Sorry, sort of newbie to Mac development. Going fine with Xcode 3.2.4, but new version is out as of today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Xcode installer will normally overwrite the older version for you automatically

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to uninstall the old XCode, it will update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that Xcode now supports installing versions side-by-side, I would suggest installing Xcode 3.2.5 in a folder called Dev325 or something and try it out first just to make sure. It's unlikely you will experience a problem, but it has been known to happen. Then, once you have used 3.2.5 for awhile and are comfortable that it is working correctly, uninstall 3.2.4 - *About Xcode.pdf* will tell you how to uninstall properly.

Comment: are you sure this won't mess up the command line tools? (if you are using gcc from command line)

Comment: The documentation states that one can install multiple versions side by side and if you look at <Developer Folder>/usr/bin, you will see the gcc tools there that will be used by that version of Xcode.

Comment: and the tools that are installed in /usr/bin like /usr/bin/gcc-4.2? If you start compiling your own apache, ruby or whatever you won't use xcode but configure scripts like other unix/linuxes do... and I wonder if those tools are also properly updated if you install the new xcode in a different folder and delete the /Developer later.

Comment: Well, the documentation does state that there can only be one version of the tools installed into /usr. If you do not want the current version of the tools replaced, unselect "UNIX Development" when installing Xcode - you will still get <Developer Folder>/usr/bin. When writing your own makefile, make it robust enough to allow one to specify the path for the tools to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to install side by side, however, to retain the ability to run 3.2.4 should anything happen. I just upgraded to 3.2.5 and my application does not run in the simulator anymore, giving out an error as follows:

> Detected an attempt to call a symbol
>   in system libraries that is not
>   present on the iPhone:
>   nanosleep$UNIX2003 called from
>   function
>   _ZN3irr16CIrrDeviceIPhone5yieldEv in image pw2009test_dbg. If you are
>   encountering this problem running a
>   simulator binary within gdb, **make
>   sure you 'set start-with-shell off'
>   first**.

This is the same issue as reported [App crashes with 4.2 iPhone simulator 'set start-with-shell off'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271480/app-crashes-with-4-2-iphone-simulator-set-start-with-shell-off). This issue specifically started after 3.2.5 upgrade.

Comment: Quick update: reinstalling 3.2.4 instantly solved the problem.